# Docusign Signature Tab size reduce

Tags: rest, docusignapi, signature

Is there is option for reduce the Size of Signature tab, through Rest API. I can see in admin(UI) we can reduce the size. So is it possible to do through API Call for DOcusign. What property can be use for provide a size.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DocuSign REST API - EnvelopeRecipientTabs: create](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipienttabs/create/#signHere)

I believe you're looking for `scaleValue` under the `signHere` tab.

Values `0.5` - `1.0` should work